# GRADLE VERSIONS 1.0-milestone and 2.2.1 compatible?

Tags: android, gradle

I have an application who is using 1.0-milestone to compile an app. I thougth that is using ROS FUERTE because is done in 2012.

But now I am usin ROS INDIGO and the gradle that I have compile before is 2.2.1.

When I try to compile the app ./gradlew debug I gare a error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':android_gingerbread_mr1:compile'.

> Could not find group:org.ros.rosjava_core, module:rosjava, version:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
>   Required by:
>     ros.android_core:android_gingerbread_mr1:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT
>   
>   How I could resolve that issue? It is 1.0-milestone gradle version compatible with my system?

Thanks million!